# how would i go about adding some paragraphs on the go and show the result to the document with paragraph tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add 3 paragraphs tags here straight from the script that prints 
   The same thing that logs on the console

```
<script >

var array= [1,2,4];
  $.each(array,function (index,value)   {
     console.log(index + ": "+value)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: **how would i go about adding some paragraphs on the go from the script and show the result to the document with paragraph tags instead of logging them to the console?**

Comment: check my answer spaceguy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w75n2180/)

```
 <script>
    var array= [1,2,4];
  $.each(array,function (index,value)   {
       $('<p>').appendTo('body').html(index + ": "+value);
  })
    </script>
```

Comment: i appreciate  your quick response but it doesnt work it doesn't create any paragraph element or nothing .-.

Comment: close enough but is there any way to do it without having already any tag elements in the document  and add them straight from the script?

Comment: i don't even know if its possible..if not then ill go with your code

Comment: what u are expecting ? @spaceguy

Comment: what im trying to do is add them to document straight from the script but without having no elements on the document already set up.. mmm is there a way to add the div to the document from the script? and then append the paragraph tag to the div?

Comment: just use `div` instead of body try that got it ?

Comment: yes exactly like that thanks alot i really appreciate your time in fact just before i read your comment i already had it but your code is much cleaner and more compact so ill go with yours heres how i did it [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gtgztkrz/)

Comment: im glad to helo you @spaceguy

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help you.

```js
var array= [1,2,4];
  $.each(array,function(index,value){
     $('<p />').appendTo('#apd').html(index + ": "+value);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='apd'></div>
```

Comment: thanks indeed that is a solution but the solution im looking for is without having any element tag on the document and create it all on the go from the script ..i dont even know if its possible

Comment: it is possible, just change #apd to body. It will create paragraphs on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<body>
<div id="data"></div>
</body>
<script>
var test="";
var array= [1,2,4];
 for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
      test += '<p>'+i+ ':'+array[i]+'</p>';
    }

    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = test;
</script>
```

**Output:**

```
0:1

1:2

2:4
```

Comment: thanks @Deena but am trying to do it in #jquery code